# How to encrypt a dynamic library such as .so file?

Tags: android, encryption, shared-libraries, reverse, ida

I've made a .so file using in Android to encode/decode some private string , but I found it's easy to decrypt the .so file by using ida ,and easy to debug with some reverse engineering software.How to encrypt the .so file ? How to use the encrypted .so file in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  A .so file is instructions to be used by the client processor.  You can leave it encrypted until you need it, but before using it you have to unencrypt it so it can be put unencrypted in memory where the processor can access it.  An encrypted .so file would need an entirely new type of architecture from the processor, to the motherboard, to RAM.  And even then the client would have to have the decryption keys, which basically means you need a cryptographically secure system with all code encrypted by keys controlled by the processor OEMs.  Which you don't want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found a way to anti-crack the .so file.

Comment: @coolcloud could you share the way you found to anti-crack .so file?